# How to synchronize two concurrent hibernate actions

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, oauth

So, I have two threads, each already in their own hibernate transaction (due to some magic I have no control over).  They both want to get an `oauth` connection, but the token has expired, so they need to refresh and update it.  This particular provider invalidates old access tokens when refreshing, so all threads must end up using the latest access token.

I have a distributed `read-write locking mechanism` (since multiple application instances) ensuring that only one thread refreshes the token of the `oauth` component, while the rest wait to get the updated one.  The `updateComponent` and `getComponent` methods each create their own new transaction within a transaction in the hopes that the flush occurs before the `write-lock` is released.  Unfortunately, this does not appear to be the case.

This is the interface for my `OauthComponent` helper

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false, rollbackFor=Throwable.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
void updateToken(String connectionId, OauthComponentDto component);

@Transactional(readOnly=true, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
<T extends OauthComponentDto> T getComponent(String connectionId);
```

And this is my oauth token refresh code:

```
// FYI, already in a transaction here.  Can't change that
final String connectionId = connection.getIdentifier();
final String lockKey = String.format("%s-refresh", connectionId);

try {  // If write-lock can be acquired, refresh the token and save to db
    getWriteLock(lockKey);  
    try {
        Oauth2ComponentDto component = oauthComponentHelper.getOauthComponent(connectionId);
        if (isExpiringSoon(component)) {
            refreshToken(component, connection);
            oauthComponentHelper.updateToken(connectionId, component);  // updates in new transaction
        }
        return component;
    } finally {
        releaseWrite(lockKey);
    }
} catch (LockNotAcquiredException e) {
    try {  // Write-lock was not acquired, so wait for read-lock to get new token from db
        getReadLock(lockKey);
        try {
            Oauth2ComponentDto component = oauthComponentHelper.getOauthComponent(connectionId);  // gets with new transaction
            if (isExpiringSoon(component)) {
                throw new ExpiredAuthorizationException();
            }
            return component;
        } finally {
            releaseRead(lockKey);
        }
    } catch (LockNotAcquiredException e2) {
        throw new ExpiredAuthorizationException();
    }
}
```

What ends up happening is that the thread waiting for the read-lock ends up using the old access token. I believe this occurs because the read-thread ends up reading from the db before the update is flushed. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You should release the lock only after the transaction has committed.

Comment: Why not use java synchronization?

Comment: @doge Won't scale beyond a single application instance.

Comment: You are exiting method(return statement) before releaseWrite in finally block.

Comment: @doge, the release call is in a finally block.

Comment: @Kayaman, that idea has definitely crossed my mind.  But how?

Comment: What do you mean how? You need to get the lock, then enter the `@Transactional` method, then after you've returned from the method the transaction has been committed and you can release the lock.

Comment: @Kayaman, that is indeed what I am doing.  `updateComponent` uses a new transaction.  But it doesn't seem like the update is actually flushed before releasing the write lock.

Comment: Ah you're right, I misread the code. You might want to turn on logging for hibernate to see what it's doing and when it's flushing.

Comment: May be I got it wrong but changing isalation level to serializable may be enough even without locking. Although performance may degrade.